# Is there a template conditional to determine whether a plugin is installed?

Tags: templating, plugins

Let's say I've got a hot plugin called Cornballer, and I'd like to avoid embarrassing template errors **if I refer to it in a template without yet installing it**.

I'd like to get away with this...

```
 {% if craft.cornballer %}

 {{ craft.cornballer.simulate('little') }}

 {% endif %}
```

...so that any cornballing is simply ignored and no errors result. But Craft allows no such thing:

> Method "cornballer" for object "Craft\CraftVariable" does not exist

Is there a way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do it:

```
{% if craft.cornballer is defined %}
    Never fear... CornBaller is here.
{% else %}
    I'm missing my CornBaller.
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Damn. I'm embarrassed that `is defined` didn't occur to me. Thank you, Brad.