# How can I check if a plugin is installed and enabled?

Tags: plugins

As the title suggests, I was wondering how to check if a certain plugin exists (and has been installed).

And secondly, check that the plugin is actually enabled.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Do you need to check from somewhere else other than the "/admin/settings/plugins" screen?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

On top of checking within the admin area, there are some other ways you can do this, both in templates and in your plugins.

**In a template**

```
{# Second argument is if you want enabled only #}
{% set plugin = craft.plugins.getPlugin('pluginHandle', false) %}

{# Now you have access to these methods... #}
{{ plugin.isEnabled() }}
{{ plugin.isInstalled() }}
```

For a full list of methods, see [`PluginVariable`](https://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/variables/PluginVariable) in craft docs.

For more info on how to get plugins within your templates, see the [`PluginsVariable`](https://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/variables/PluginsVariable), note this is different from `PluginVariable`.

**In your plugin**

To check a plugin from within your own plugin:

```
// Again, second arg is if you just want enabled plugins
$plugin = craft()->plugins->getPlugin('pluginHandle', false);

// Then you can do things like:
$plugin->isInstalled
$plugin->isEnabled;
```

See the [`PluginService`](https://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/services/PluginsService) and also the [`BasePlugin`](https://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/etc/plugins/BasePlugin) for more info.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thanks Alec, this is exactly what I was after. To elaborate on my purpose for this: My plugin relies on the basis that certain fieldtypes are created first. I could check for the fieldtype itself, but I found myself doing a lot of long winded (is defined and is not null and *fieldtype*|length) checks that was making the code look untidy. A simple check to see if the plugin is active in the first place allow me to create more informative conditions. Now I can tell the user "This page isn't working because..." as apposed to an immediate error page as soon as the plugin is installed.

Comment: No worries! and if your plugin is relying on certain fieldtypes being created, are these something you could create within the `onAfterInstall` method on the plugin? that way you can always be sure the fieldtypes will be there and will also minimise user error, fieldtype handle mismatches and so forth.

Comment: Am I right in thinking that `pluginHandle` corresponds to the directory name of the plugin? Couldn't find any documentation on this, but after a bit of trial and error that's what worked for me.

Comment: For craft cms 3 see me answer.

Answer (score 6):

For craft cms 3

```
{% set plugin = craft.app.plugins.getPlugin('plugin-handle', false) %}


{% if plugin is not null and plugin.isInstalled %}
....
    call plugin related stuff here
.....
{% endif %}
```

> To check plugin handle.

1. Open composer.json of your plugin.
2. Search for `handle` param in that file, that's the plugin handle.

Answer (score 4):

A simple way to check that a plugin is both installed and enabled is to use Twig's `is defined` test (since `craft.pluginHandle` is defined only if the plugin is both installed and enabled):

```
{% if craft.pluginHandle is defined %}
  ...
{% endif %}
```

(Credit due to [this answer](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/7028/328))

Answer (score 3):

It should show up in the control panel in the plugins section. It will show the name of the plugin and if it is enabled. I've had issues when i didn't setup the folder correctly. Double check the plugin documentation, it should tell you what folder to place within the craft plugins directory.