# Is there a fallback when a Twig extension is not enabled?

Tags: plugin-development, templating

So I have a plugin with a Twig Extension that does it's thing. If I were to disable my plugin I will get the expected error:

> The "extensionName" extension is not enabled.

Whenever I'm referring to anything to do with my plugin, I rely on the usual "*is defined*", "*is not empty*", "*|default()*", etc... options as appropriate fallbacks/checks incase my plugin fails.

However, short of doing a full [check on wether my plugin is installed](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/10632/how-can-i-check-if-a-plugin-is-installed-and-enabled) everytime, there doesn't seem to be an elegant solution for checking extensions are enabled until it's too late (and the page fails to load).

Any ideas on a workaround?

Answer (score 2):

I can't think of a native way to do this, but Twig does have a [hasExtension](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/blob/1.x/lib/Twig/Environment.php#L736) method, which you could make use of in a Craft plugin.  But if you wrote a plugin to utilize it (similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28772193/684)) obviously that wouldn't help if the plugin was disabled or uninstalled.

Alternatively, you can add this as a [feature request](http://feedback.buildwithcraft.com) to add to Craft natively. If you go that route, be sure and go into details on your specific use-case as I'm not sure I'm following it 100% here.

Comment: I would vote for that feature request, here's an example use case... The common "best approach" to managing DB & file syncing across environments is **files go up, database comes down.** But if you need files to go up to a live site which include a new Twig filter, you've got to do it in multiple steps: (1) Upload plugin with filter, (2) Enable plugin, (3) Upload templates which use the new filter. Allowing Craft to fail gracefully when a filter doesn't exist would make it possible to upload everything at once, greatly simplifying this process.