# Checking if a plugin is installed or enabled are ignored by Twig Extensions

Tags: plugins

A while ago I asked how to check [if a plugin is enabled/installed](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/10632/how-can-i-check-if-a-plugin-is-installed-and-enabled). I've since used a couple methods to do my checks:

```
{% set plugin = craft.plugins.getPlugin('myPlugin', false) %}

{{ plugin.isEnabled() ? 'plugin enabled' : 'plugin disabled'}} <br/>
{{ plugin.isInstalled() ? 'plugin installed' : 'plugin not installed'}} <br/>

{{ craft.myPlugin is defined ? 'plugin true' : 'plugin false' }}
```

Now I [recall this working with Twig Extension functions and filters too](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/11899/is-there-a-fallback-when-a-twig-extension-is-not-enabled). It wasn't pretty, but it worked.

I may wrong, but I think one of the Craft CMS Updates have broken this. Because as-of-late, when I do something like this:

```
{{ craft.myPlugin is defined ? myFunction() }}
```

or

```
{{ craft.myPlugin is defined ? someVariable|myFilter() }}
```

(myFunction being a twig function, and myFilter being a twig filter)... I get an error:

> Unknown "myFunction" function

Another new *change/bug* I've noticed (related to this); if a database can't be connected to and devMode is off, I will get this instead of the 503 error template.

> Unknown "myFunction" function in "_layouts/main" at line 85.

It's as if the Twig functions/filters get priority over anything else. Am I making this up, and this has always been the case? Or has something changed?

Comment: I'm also experiencing some what Mark Bolton is seeing... that is if a plugin is _disabled_ or _not installed_: the conditionals fail with the `Unknown "myFunction" function`. For example, trying to confirm that [Cookies](https://github.com/nystudio107/cookies/) is installed & enabled, following throws the Unknown function error if it's not installed: `{{ craft.cookies is defined ? getCookie() }}` However, the following does not throw the error: `{{ craft.cookies is defined ? craft.cookies.get() }}` Skimming through the Cookies code, I don't see anything immediately obvious as to the difference

Answer (score 2):

I just a test of this locally in a sample plugin and I get expected behavior.

If I install and enable the plugin in Craft and use this in a template:

```
{% set plugin = craft.plugins.getPlugin('myPlugin', false) %}

{{ plugin.isEnabled() ? 'plugin enabled' : 'plugin disabled'}}<br/>
{{ plugin.isInstalled() ? 'plugin installed' : 'plugin not installed'}}<br/>

{{ craft.myPlugin is defined ? 'plugin true' : 'plugin false' }}
```

I get this output:

```
plugin enabled 
plugin installed 
plugin true
```

If I add a Twig Extension class to the plugin, then register a `myPluginTestFunction` function that outputs "It Works"... i.e.

```
public function getFunctions()
{
    return array(
        'myPluginTestFunction' => new Twig_Filter_Method($this, 'myPluginTestFunction', array('is_safe' => array('html'))),
    );
}

public function myPluginTestFunction()
{
    return 'It Works';
}
```

Then I do this is a template:

```
{{ craft.myPlugin is defined ? myPluginTestFunction() }}
```

Then I get the expected output of:

```
It Works
```