# How can I check if a plugin is installed and enabled, in Craft 3?

Tags: plugins, craft3

In [a question I asked](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/10632/how-can-i-check-if-a-plugin-is-installed-and-enabled) a few years ago, it was very simple to perform a check on wether a plugin was installed or not.

As of Craft 3, the same methods don't seem to work. The likes of this always returns `true`:

```
{{ craft.myPlugin is defined ? 'Installed' : 'Not Installed' }}
```

Is there another way to determine if a specific plugin is installed and enabled?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PHP

```
\Craft::$app->plugins->isPluginInstalled('plugin-handle')
```

Twig

```
{% set installed = craft.app.plugins.isPluginInstalled('plugin-handle') %}
```

There is also a `isPluginDisabled` and a `isPluginEnabled` function.
Here is a class reference [craft\services\Plugins](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-services-plugins.html#isPluginInstalled()-detail)

Comment: I think that has to be a record for the fastest correct answer of all time :) Thank you Robin, that's perfect.

Comment: Any tips on how to determine a plugin's handle?

Comment: @Henry the plugins table in the database has a `handle` column